# How to put two cck fields in add content page in drupal 6

Tags: 6, entities

0 down vote favorite

I have created a content type in Drupal 6.

I want to add an input field to a number and a select(dropdown) field to get Year/months. They should be next to each other in add content page.

User enters for example 3 months by typing 3 in text input and select months from dropdown. But I don't know can I do it in Druapl 6 using CCK.

If I add two fields they will be shown with their label but I want they be next to each other without any label between them.

How can I do it?

Comment: Are you able to directly modify the code inside your theme? (If so, it could be as simple as adding a few lines to your theme's css file.)

Comment: Is it possible only in that way?